# Directional deriviation given two points as the direction

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given $$z=x^2y+y^2$$.
How can I calculate the directional deriviation at $M(1,2)$ in the direction of $MM_1$ where $M_1(4,0)$?
I know how to do this when given a vector and not the two ends of it.
This question is really about how to convert the points to a vector I can work with.

Comment: The vector in the direction of $MM_1$ would be determined by the vector $(4 - 1,0 - 2) = (3,-2)$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (4,5).(3/sqrt13,-2/sqrt13)=2/sqrt13. It goes as follows:The direction vector is (4-1,0-2) whose unit vector is  (3/sqrt 13,-2/sqrt13). The gradiant at the point (1,2) is (z_x,z_y)=(4,5). Now the answer is (4,5).(3/sqrt13,-2/sqrt13)=2/sqrt13.